# Vue.js how to have Axios GET and POST request every 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, setinterval

I'm trying to have an Axios GET request to be called every 5 minutes, in my .then on the Axios GET request I parse the data and then POST it in a nested Axios request. The POST request though is being triggered before the 5-minute mark. I've tried having them as two separate setIntervals but that hasn't worked for me either. Does anyone have any suggestions and know why the POST is being triggered before the 5 minutes is up.

```
setInterval(() => {
let uri = 'https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/5m'
axios.get(uri).then(response => {
console.log(response.data)
this.prices = response.data.data;
this.timestamp = response.data.timestamp
for(const index in this.prices){
  this.fiveMinPrice = {
    "id": index,
    "avgHighPrice": this.prices[index].avgHighPrice,
    "avgLowPrice": this.prices[index].avgLowPrice,
    "highPriceVolume": this.prices[index].highPriceVolume,
    "lowPriceVolume": this.prices[index].lowPriceVolume,
    "timestamp": this.timestamp     
  } 
  this.fiveMinPrices.push(this.fiveMinPrice)
}
let url = '/api/5m/'   
axios.post(url, this.fiveMinPrices).then(response => {
  console.log(response)       
}).catch(function(error){
  console.log(error)
})
}).catch(function(error){
  console.log(error)
})
this.fiveMinPrices = []
  this.prices = []
  this.fiveMinPrice = {}
  this.timestamp = 0  
}, 300000);
```

Comment: "Does anyone have any suggestions and know why the POST is being triggered before the 5 minutes is up" - because you already set an interval before and didn't clean it? It is a mistake to not clean up global behaviour in components.

Comment: I just unnested the post and it seems to have fixed it